VBA error 2467 "Me" reserved word acts inconsistently after moving to Access 365
frm_Session has a WithEvents declaration, and handles the event ChangedUnitInSession as follows:
Private Sub changePublisher_ChangedUnitInSession()
    Me.UsedTime = SessionUsedTime(getSessionTime)
    Me.UnitsInSession.Requery

This has always worked fine under Access 2003. When the database is moved to Access 365 however it fails – half the time! Here’s the sequence:
Open form 1st time; works fine
Open form 2nd time; crashes
Open form 3rd time; works fine
Open form 4th time; crashes

The inconsistency of crashes is one puzzle. The other puzzle is the crash itself: runtime error 2467 "The expression you entered refers to an object that is closed or doesn't exist". The expression being complained about is the Me reserved word. Why would Me exist half the time, in a Form that is demonstrably open? Here's what I learn from the Immediate window:
? Me.Used.Time.Value  = error 2467
? Me.Controls.Count = error 2467
? Me.Name = error 2467
? isMissing(Me) = False
? isObject(Me) = True
? TypeName(Me) = Form_frm_Session

By the way, the database was in .mdb format but converting it to .accdb (thank you, CHill60) made no difference.
I've tried the following:
private myForm as Form_frm_Session

and during the Form_Load() procedure set myForm = Me and changing other code accordingly. Still, it crashes every other time. The error number remains 2467 but when I use the Immediate window
? myForm.Name or  
? myForm.Form.Name  
the error is 5, "invalid procedure call or argument". 

I'd appreciate any ideas for how I can get to the bottom of this. Thanks.

An update, 2024-09-04:
changePublisher_ChangedUnitInSession() is triggered by various forms and subforms. frm_Session needs to sink all these events. But in one case it was triggered by its own subform. In that case I replicated the code in a simple Sub:
Public Sub updateSessionForm()
    ' This is just a copy of changePublisher_ChangedUnitInSession()
    ' which can be called from a child subform,
    ' to avoid a bug we encounter when sinking published events.
    
    Me.UsedTime.Value = SessionUsedTime(getSessionTime)
    Me.UnitsInSession.Requery
End Sub

and when the subform calls its parent's updateSessionForm() everything works fine. The references to Me are fine. From this I deduce that something is going awry when the event gets triggered, raised and sunk.

First thing that I would do is rule out the format being the issue - convert a copy to .accdb and see if can recreate issue. Is there a specific reason you are using the old format?

That's very sensible, CHill60. I've tried it, but it made no difference. Thanks.

At least that's out of the way. Silly question but have you tried 'Database Tools', 'Compact & Repair Database'?

10% chance, check everytime before using the Me. if it is the right one with If TypeName(Me) = "Form_frm_Session"

50% chance, check out which events are executed in which order. For instance just opening a form should invoke these Open → Load → Resize → Activate → Current. If you change a value during the Form_Open, other events could happen and cause a crash. More info on --1-- and --2--

Compact & Repair Database is something I do so often, I wonder whether the software gets tired of me! Am currently putting Open, Load, Current events under the microscope. One thing I've found is that if another module requests frm.FilterOn=True the Current event gets triggered a second time. I've changed this so that only the form itself sets FilterOn=True and this has eliminated the second Current event. Still battling this ...

Testing whether TypeName(Me) = "Form_frm_Session" is a nice idea but doesn't change anything, because the test is true even when Me is unusable, as in my original example.

Please see my 2024-09-04 update to the original post.

this is not gonna be a solution.  I just want to use this way of "answering" to properly communicate what my ideas are for debugging the situation.  My main concern is your phrase "triggered by its own subform".  I remember having issues whit such a situation myself. As you wrote "triggered by various forms and subforms", I want to know exactly who is doing what when and in which order. I want to know for sure when and how Me.UsedTime = something is triggered/executed.
-1- changes in the procedure definition: 
Private Sub changePublisher_ChangedUnitInSession(str_CalledBy as string) 
Public Sub updateSessionForm(str_CalledBy as string)
-2- defining a counter somewhere public for knowing how many times Me.UsedTime is changed.  I am gonna use Public lng_NumberOfChanges_MeUsedTime as Long
-3- changes in the procedure code: 
Debug.Print "changePublisher_ChangedUnitInSession"/"updateSessionForm"
Debug.Print lng_NumberOfChanges_MeUsedTime & " -> " & str_CalledBy 
Me.UsedTime.Value = Sess...

-4- defining the str_CalledBy.  Now comes the difficult part, writing a good description for every place where the subroutine is called...  For instance, we need to know who Me is all the time.
Let us hope for the best.

Many thanks for your very thoughtful suggestions, @JonRo!
I can see the value in what you suggest. Just like you say,
it will be valuable to know exactly who is doing what, when.
Maybe that's why I changed my code a few hours before
seeing your answer... but a little differently. I gave up entirely
on the RaiseEvent and WithEvent features of Access 365
because they seemed untrustworthy. I replaced them with a
brute-force method...

Each module that wants to "raise" an event
trawls through Access.Forms looking for those modules that I
know should sink the event. Then it calls a public Sub in those
modules. It's not good coding practice because the sinking
form name and procedure name are hard-coded. Yuck!
But it works totally. I no longer encounter any instance where
"Me" is invalid.

I may soon post my next problem. Like the "Me" problem, it just might
be related to the fact that I have multiple copies of a form open,
each of them created with Set frm = New Form_frm_Session
which is important to this application, and was learned from the
Access 2000 Developer's Handbook. And just like the "Me" problem,
it wasn't a problem at all before migrating to Access 365.

Sorry I didn't post my "solution" a couple of hours earlier, but I was testing it to make sure it really did work ...

I think the situation was between shore and ship.
Practice showed now that it was too complicated to work only with forms.
Perhaps the problem is also too simple to code with a class module...

I understand you are calling a public Sub in the module of a form?  If possible, do not keep public stuff in a form-module. Place it in a seperate "code"-module.  more info --1--.  more info --2--.
